# Отладка / отображение тел в Box2d

Tags: c++, sfml, box2d

Есть проект на c++, с подключенными SFML и Box2d. Как отобразить каркасы, вершины и т.д.(Как в официальном Testbed) тел из Box2d ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам надо будет реализовать интерфейс `b2Draw` и зарегистрировать его вызвав `b2World::SetDebugDraw`. Тогда при каждом вызове `b2World::Step` экземпляр вашего класса будет получать команды на отрисовку.

Comment: А нет случайно готового решения ?

Comment: @RIDER Наверняка есть, SFML - достаточно распространенная библиотека.

Answer (score 1):

**DebugDraw.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "header.h"

struct b2AABB;

// This class implements debug drawing callbacks that are invoked
// inside b2World::Step.
class DebugDraw : public b2Draw
{
private:
    SDL_Renderer* renderer;

public:
    DebugDraw(SDL_Renderer*);

    void DrawPolygon(const b2Vec2* vertices, int32 vertexCount, const b2Color& color);

    void DrawSolidPolygon(const b2Vec2* vertices, int32 vertexCount, const b2Color& color);

    void DrawCircle(const b2Vec2& center, float32 radius, const b2Color& color);

    void DrawSolidCircle(const b2Vec2& center, float32 radius, const b2Vec2& axis, const b2Color& color);

    void DrawSegment(const b2Vec2& p1, const b2Vec2& p2, const b2Color& color);

    void DrawTransform(const b2Transform& xf);

    void DrawPoint(const b2Vec2& p, float32 size, const b2Color& color);

    //void DrawString(int x, int y, const char* string, ...);

    //void DrawString(const b2Vec2& p, const char* string, ...);

    void DrawAABB(b2AABB* aabb, const b2Color& color);

};
```

**DebugDraw.cpp**

```
#include "DebugDraw.h" 



DebugDraw::DebugDraw(SDL_Renderer* rend):renderer(rend)
{   }

void DebugDraw::DrawPolygon(const b2Vec2* vertices, int32 vertexCount, const b2Color& color)
{


    Sint16 xs[8];
    Sint16 ys[8];

    int32 i;
    for (i = 0; i < vertexCount; ++i) {
        SDL_Point p = m_Core.worldToPixel( vertices[i] );
        xs[i] = p.x;
        ys[i] = p.y;
    }

    polygonRGBA(renderer, xs, ys, vertexCount, (uint8)(color.r*255), (uint8)(color.g * 255), (uint8)(color.b * 255), SDL_ALPHA_OPAQUE);
}

void DebugDraw::DrawSolidPolygon(const b2Vec2* vertices, int32 vertexCount, const b2Color& color)
{



    Sint16 xs[8];
    Sint16 ys[8];

    int32 i;
    for (i = 0; i < vertexCount; ++i) {
        SDL_Point p = m_Core.worldToPixel( vertices[i] );
        xs[i] = p.x;
        ys[i] = p.y;
    }

    filledPolygonRGBA(renderer, xs, ys, vertexCount, (uint8)(color.r * 128), (uint8)(color.g * 128), (uint8)(color.b * 128), 128);
    polygonRGBA(renderer, xs, ys, vertexCount, (uint8)(color.r * 255), (uint8)(color.g * 255), (uint8)(color.b * 255), SDL_ALPHA_OPAQUE);
}

void DebugDraw::DrawCircle(const b2Vec2& center, float32 radius, const b2Color& color)
{



    const float32 k_segments = 16.0f;
    const float32 k_increment = 2.0f * b2_pi / k_segments;
    float32 theta = 0.0f;

    Sint16 xs[16];
    Sint16 ys[16];

    int32 i;
    for (i = 0; i < k_segments; ++i) {
        b2Vec2 v = center + radius * b2Vec2(cosf(theta), sinf(theta));
        SDL_Point p = m_Core.worldToPixel( v );
        xs[i] = p.x;
        ys[i] = p.y;
        theta += k_increment;
    }

    polygonRGBA(renderer, xs, ys, (int)k_segments, (uint8)(color.r * 255), (uint8)(color.g * 255), (uint8)(color.b * 255), SDL_ALPHA_OPAQUE);
}

void DebugDraw::DrawSolidCircle(const b2Vec2& center, float32 radius, const b2Vec2& axis, const b2Color& color)
{

    const float32 k_segments = 16.0f;
    const float32 k_increment = 2.0f * b2_pi / k_segments;
    float32 theta = 0.0f;

    Sint16 xs[16];
    Sint16 ys[16];

    int32 i;
    for (i = 0; i < k_segments; ++i) {
        b2Vec2 v = center + radius * b2Vec2(cosf(theta), sinf(theta));
        SDL_Point p = m_Core.worldToPixel( v );
        xs[i] = p.x;
        ys[i] = p.y;
        theta += k_increment;
    }

    filledPolygonRGBA(renderer, xs, ys, (int)k_segments, (uint8)(color.r * 128), (uint8)(color.g * 128), (uint8)(color.b * 128), 128);
    polygonRGBA(renderer, xs, ys, (int)k_segments, (uint8)(color.r * 255), (uint8)(color.g * 255), (uint8)(color.b * 255), SDL_ALPHA_OPAQUE);

    b2Vec2 p = center + radius * axis;
    SDL_Point p1i = m_Core.worldToPixel(p);
    SDL_Point p2i = m_Core.worldToPixel(center);
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, (uint8)(color.r * 255), (uint8)(color.g * 255), (uint8)(color.b * 255), SDL_ALPHA_OPAQUE);
    SDL_RenderDrawLine(renderer, p1i.x, p1i.y, p2i.x, p2i.y);
}

void DebugDraw::DrawSegment(const b2Vec2& p1, const b2Vec2& p2, const b2Color& color)
{
    SDL_Point p1i = m_Core.worldToPixel(p1);
    SDL_Point p2i = m_Core.worldToPixel(p2);

    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, (uint8)(color.r * 255), (uint8)(color.g * 255), (uint8)(color.b * 255), SDL_ALPHA_OPAQUE);
    SDL_RenderDrawLine(renderer, p1i.x, p1i.y, p2i.x, p2i.y);
}

void DebugDraw::DrawTransform(const b2Transform& xf)
{



    b2Vec2 p1 = xf.p, p2;
    const float32 k_axisScale = 0.4f;
    p2 = p1 + k_axisScale * xf.q.GetXAxis();

    SDL_Point p1i = m_Core.worldToPixel(p1);
    SDL_Point p2i = m_Core.worldToPixel(p2);

    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 0, 0, SDL_ALPHA_OPAQUE);
    SDL_RenderDrawLine(renderer, p1i.x, p1i.y, p2i.x, p2i.y);

    p2 = p1 + k_axisScale * xf.q.GetYAxis();
    p2i = m_Core.worldToPixel(p2);
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 255, 0, SDL_ALPHA_OPAQUE);
    SDL_RenderDrawLine(renderer, p1i.x, p1i.y, p2i.x, p2i.y);
}

void DebugDraw::DrawPoint(const b2Vec2& p, float32 size, const b2Color& color)
{



    SDL_Point pi = m_Core.worldToPixel(p);

    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, (uint8)(color.r * 255), (uint8)(color.g * 255), (uint8)(color.b * 255), SDL_ALPHA_OPAQUE);
    SDL_RenderDrawPoint(renderer, pi.x, pi.y);
}

void DebugDraw::DrawAABB(b2AABB* aabb, const b2Color& color)
{



    SDL_Point lowerBound = m_Core.worldToPixel(aabb->lowerBound);
    SDL_Point upperBound = m_Core.worldToPixel(aabb->upperBound);

    Sint16 xs[4];
    Sint16 ys[4];

    xs[0] = lowerBound.x;
    ys[0] = lowerBound.y;

    xs[1] = upperBound.x;
    ys[1] = lowerBound.y;

    xs[2] = upperBound.x;
    ys[2] = upperBound.y;

    xs[3] = lowerBound.x;
    ys[3] = upperBound.y;

    polygonRGBA(renderer, xs, ys, 4, (uint8)(color.r * 255), (uint8)(color.g * 255), (uint8)(color.b * 255), SDL_ALPHA_OPAQUE);
}
```

**Core.h**

```
DebugDraw*      debugdraw;
```

**Core.cpp**

```
//Создаем объекты Рисования
    debugdraw = new DebugDraw (renderer);
    debugdraw->SetFlags(0x0003);
    World->SetDebugDraw(debugdraw);
```

**в цикле программы**

```
if (Debugdraw == 1) 
{
 World->DrawDebugData();                    
}
```

**функция worldToPixel**

```
sf::Vector2f Core::worldToPixel(b2Vec2 pos)
{
    sf::Vector2f p;

    p.x = pos.x * SCALE - camera.left;//тут свою камеру вставляй
    p.y = pos.y * SCALE - camera.top; //тут свою камеру вставляй
    return p;
}
```

Comment: в принципе этот код в тестбеде написан как бэ....